# inputs in c# for console apps in vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, console-application

i tried to test my dum-dum brain by making a console game because i thought that i was gud at programming, and got stuck on the inventory (i.e. going through a `foreach` for each item in the inventory when you press 'I') but realised i'm too dum-dum for that. here's what i wrote:

```
string i;
var input = Console.ReadKey();
if (input = 'I') {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Inventory)
    {
        i += $"{item.Key}: {item.Value}";
    }
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("(Press 'I' to open your inventory.)");
}
```

i know, this could kill a PROgrammer (i'm so unfunny). here were the error messages:

```
    C:\Documents\new pogram\internet be broke 2 electric boogaloo.cs(19,13): error CS0103: The name 'I' does not exist in the current context 
    
    C:\Documents\new pogram\internet be broke 2 electric boogaloo.cs(22,9): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'i' [C:\Users\lewis_pulfff2\OneDrive\Documents\new pogram\new pogram.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

i tried looking else ware, but the samples didn't work.

arigatogozaimasu (and gomennasorry) in advance :D.

Comment: You need to initialize your string (so either `string i = "";` or `string i = String.Empty;`) and remember that to test for equality, you need `==`.

Comment: `+=` needs an existing string to append on to, and your initial declaration of i starts out as null as you have it.

Comment: this code doesnt match those error messages -

Comment: "==" (comparison) and "=" (assignment) are *VERY* different in C#.  And "Pogram" sounds like something very bad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogrom.  "Electric Boogaloo" can also mean something very bad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogaloo_movement

Comment: @paulsm4 I think the latter is a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakin%27_2:_Electric_Boogaloo.  I appreciate that you are being sensitive to others, either way!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you used to have

```
   if (input = I)
```

but changed that before posting the code - this was the cause of the first error.

also you mean

```
   if (input == 'I')  <<<  '==' means compare '=' means assign
```

EDIT

plus ReadKey returns more than the key press - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-6.0

so you need

```
  if(input.Key == 'I')
```

THe second error comes from here

```
 string i;   <<<<======= this doesnt create an empty string (i is null)
```

you need

```
string i = "";
var input = Console.ReadKey();
if (input == 'I') {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Inventory)
    {
        i += $"{item.Key}: {item.Value}";
    }
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("(Press 'I' to open your inventory.)");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, at least for me i got an error saying that ' '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ConsoleKeyInfo' and 'char' '. i probably just committed stupid again tho.

Comment: @ramaa see edit